# Configure nginx serve python files

Tags: nginx

I have some python files on my server and some links pointing at them. When user clicks on any link the file is viewed in the browser window. I want browsers to start downloading process instead. Can I control this?

Is there some HTTP header to be set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a mime type set for .py files?

If not, check do you have a default_type option in the http section of the config. If the default_type isn't set nginx will set text/plain as default. Entering py in the list of mime types should produce the behaviour you want.